0 being added at beginning of array in Assembly RISC32
I'm coding my very first project in Assembly using RISC V 32 architecture and the RARS simulator and I'm having some issues with my code.
The code needs to prompt the user for an array size and ask for integers to populate the array and then it has to calculate the median of this 1 dimensional array. To sort the array I'm using a bubble sort algorithm, but when I try to print out the array after it has been sorted, a 0 gets added to the first index of the array. I don't really know what is causing it, but I believe the problem is related to the bubble sort, since the algorithm is able to print the array just fine if I skip the bubble sort. If anyone could help me by pointing out what is wrong with my code, I'd very much appreciate it.
Here is the code:
 .data
.align 2          # Align the following data to a word boundary (4 bytes)
str:
    .string "Enter an integer\n"
space_char:
    .string " "
array_size:
    .string "Insert array size\n"
array:
    .space 1000  # Allocate space for the array, must be a multiple of 4

.text
.globl main

main:
    la a1, array       # load address of array into a1
    
    la a0, array_size  # load address of array_size into a0
    li a7, 4           # syscall for print string
    ecall
    
    li a7, 5           # syscall for read integer from user
    ecall
    mv t2, a0          # move input (array size) from a0 to t2
    
    li t0, 0           # index of the array

input_loop:
    la a0, str         # load address of string into a0
    li a7, 4           # syscall for print string
    ecall
    
    li a7, 5           # syscall for read integer from user
    ecall
    
    sb a0, 0(a1)       # Store the integer into the array at current index
    
    addi a1, a1, 4     # Move to the next integer space in the array
    addi t0, t0, 1     # Increment the index
    blt t0, t2, input_loop  # Loop back if more inputs are needed
    
    # Reset the array address for sorting
    la a1, array

    li s1, 0          # Initialize outer loop counter
outer_loop:
    li s2, 0          # Initialize inner loop counter
    la a0, array      # Load address of array into a0

inner_loop:
    addi a3, a0, 4    # Load address of next integer into a3
    lb t0, 0(a0)      # Load current integer's bytes of array into t0
    lb t1, 0(a3)      # Load next integer's bytes of array into t1
    blt t0, t1, no_swap

    # Swap t0 and t1
    sb t1, 0(a0)
    sb t0, 0(a3)

no_swap:
    addi a0, a0, 4    # Move to the next integer in the array
    addi s2, s2, 1    # Increment the inner loop counter
    blt s2, t2, inner_loop  # Loop back if more integers are to be swapped

    addi s1, s1, 1    # Increment the outer loop counter
    blt s1, t2, outer_loop  # Continue to the next pass

    # Print sorted array
    la a1, array     # Reset array address for printing
    li t0, 0         # Reset index

print_loop:
    lb a0, 0(a1)     # Load integer from array byte by byte
    li a7, 1         # syscall to print integer
    ecall
    
    la a0, space_char  # Load address of space character
    li a7, 4          # syscall to print string
    ecall
    
    addi a1, a1, 4   # Move to the next integer in the array
    addi t0, t0, 1   # Increment index
    blt t0, t2, print_loop  # Loop back if more integers are to be printed

    # Exit the program
    li a7, 10        # syscall for exit
    ecall

I've tried checking the registers data to see when it happens and the value 0 appears to get added to the array right after the Bubble sort ends.

Use the debugger to single step and see where that zero comes from.  It might be coming from 1 past the end of the input if you have an off by one error.  Use the smallest possible input during initial debugging, such as 1 element in the array, then later 2 elements.  Also, what you can do is single step the assembly and the working C or Java version of the algorithm to see where the assembly makes a bad choice in control flow (off by one in for-loop iteration count) or otherwise maybe accesses the array out of bounds.
